# Ignore Special Characters - Web API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

**PROBLEM:**
Special characters particularly $ and £ are causing inconsistent behaviour in Web Api - ASP.NET C#. After calling the API the result is sometimes -

RESULT: {"Message":"An error has occurred."}

- REQUEST FORMAT: url + Message;
- FULL API CALL: ".........//api/data?Message=Test%20For%20%245700.00%20at%20"
- MESSAGE: "Test For $5700.00 at "

What I've tried

1. Using **Uri.EscapeDataString(request);** to call the API, but the result is still not always 100% successful (50% of times it passes, the remaining 50% of times it comes up with the error message above)
2. Removing the $ or £ symbol, it passes every time

QUESTION:
Is there a way to allow special characters to pass through the API (just as a string)? Is there any way to get just the plain string back, even when a special character is included? Here's some code below that gets the message -

```
public List<Results> Get(string Message)
{
   //DO SOMETHING WITH THE MESSAGE AS A STRING & RETURN RESULTS
}
```

Also, here's how I'm calling the API -

```
//CALLING API STEPS
string url = ".....//api/data?Message=";
string message = "Test For $5700.00 at ";
string completeURL = url + Uri.EscapeDataString(message);
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(completeURL);
```

I've added some additional test results below -

**TEST RESULT - PASS**

```
string url = ".....//api/data?Message=";
string message = "Test For $5700.00 at ";
message = message.Replace("$", "%24");//Adding this line before the URL-encoding fixes the problem
string completeURL = url + Uri.EscapeDataString(message);
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(completeURL);
//PASS - COMPLETE URL: ".....//api/data?Message=Test%20for%20%25245700.00%20at%20"
//RESULT - API CALL SUCCESSFUL
```

**TEST RESULT - FAIL**

```
string url = ".....//api/data?Message=";
string message = "Test For $5700.00 at ";
string completeURL = url + Uri.EscapeDataString(message);
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(completeURL);
//FAIL - COMPLETE URL: ".....//api/data?Message=Test%20for%20%245700.00%20at%20"
//RESULT - EXCEPTION -> "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
```

Comment: My guess is that you're not correctly escaping the query parameter. Please show exactly how you're calling the API - you shouldn't just append arbitrary text to a URL; it should be URL-encoded.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question with the details of how I'm calling the API. I also thought the Uri.EscapeDataString handles all the encoding.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect it to as well, but you previously just said "REQUEST FORMAT: url + Message" which isn't the same thing at all. (You mentioned `Uri.EscapeDataString(request)`, but that's not the same as message... this is why showing the actual code is much more useful.) Now, you say this *sometimes* causes problems - could you give more details about that? Is it literally inconsistent between calls to the same URI, or does it always fail or always succeed for any given message?

Comment: Oh I see. Update - it's also now reproducible consistently: While debugging exception I get is "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

This workaround fixes it though: 
string message = "Test For $5700.00 at "; 
message = message.Replace("$", "%24");//Adding this line before the URL-encoding fixes the problem
string completeURL = url + Uri.EscapeDataString(message);

It's odd and I wonder why I have to replace the $ sign, before URL-encoding the message...

Comment: I suggest you put that information into the question, along with the final URL in each case.

Comment: Thank you, I've recorded the test results and added it to the question.

Comment: Dig into your error logs a little deeper. `(500) Internal Server Error` usually means something went wrong in _your_ code, not in Web API itself. Does your `Get` method get invoked? What is the value of the Message parameter at that point? I would guess your "DO SOMETHING WITH THE MESSAGE..." code is where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone. Problem finally solved, it actually wasn't the special character - so I spent some time digging deeper into the Web API and I found another exception (array out of bounds) buried in the code. It was in the //DO SOMETHING WITH THE MESSAGE...section. This other exception then triggered the (500) Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for adding the test results:

```
//PASS - COMPLETE URL: ".....//api/data?Message=Test%20for%20%25245700.00%20at%20"
//RESULT - API CALL SUCCESSFUL

//FAIL - COMPLETE URL: ".....//api/data?Message=Test%20for%20%245700.00%20at%20"
//RESULT - EXCEPTION -> "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."
```

It seems clear what's happening:

- In the "success" case you're  passing a percent sign ("%", hex 0x25) and the value "245700.00".
- In the "failing" case, you're passing a dollar sign (0x24) and the value "5700.00"".
- Your application (the *application*, not Web API) is failing when it tries to read the "$".

I suspect the failing case (HTTP error 500) *AND* the "success" case are *BOTH* wrong.

I think you meant the value to be "5700.00", not "245700.00".

SUGGESTION:

- Eliminate the "$"
  ... or ...
- Modify your app to expect (and accept) the leading "$" sign.

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful analysis, it steered me to look closer at certain sections of the code (Application & the Web API). I've added a fix to the Web API after digging deeper. Those special characters trigger the bug but for other reasons - not exactly because they are special characters. It really looked like it was due to the special characters but I found an underlying bug in the Web API with an out of bounds array and after fixing that bug now every test passes.

Comment: I believe you.  Although it's a bit surprising that the SHORTER input string, with the SMALLER numeric value would trigger an out-of-bounds exception, while the LONGER/LARGER value wouldn't.  In any case - glad you found the problem.  SUGGESTION: Please feel free to "upvote" the response if you found it helpful.